# How to solve TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, http

I receive HTTP requests with the binary type and the error exists when I split them. I tried to fix it but it doesn't work. Thank you for your help.

```
client_request, addr = s.accept()
data = client_request.recv(5999)
if not data:
   break
# parse the first line
data.decode('utf-8')
first_line = data.split('\n')[0]
```

Comment: With `data.decode('utf-8')` you decode the byte sequence to a string and don't use the result. You need `data = data.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: thank you too much, I fixed it. Have a good day